# How to insert a photo from the database into the slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

There is a code that produces photos added to the database. I tried to insert this code into regular js sliders, but all I got was a bunch of photos superimposed on each other and a slider that didn't work.

How can I make a slider out of this code?

```
include('dat.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabl_image ORDER BY image_id DESC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query); 
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$number_of_rows = $statement->rowCount();
if($number_of_rows > 0)
{
 $count = 0;
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $count ++; 
  $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td><img src="files/'.$row["image_name"].'" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="'.$row["image_description"].'" title="'.$row["image_description"].'"/></td>
  </tr>
  ';
 }
}
else
{
 $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td colspan="6" align="center">Данные не найдены</td>
  </tr>
 ';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Here is how the code looks when this script is in the slider

```
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked="">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3">
   <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn4">
  
  <div class="switch">
    <label for="btn1"></label>
    <label for="btn2"></label>
    <label for="btn3"></label>
    <label for="btn4"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slides">
      
  
   <img src="files/dsc09678.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
  
  
   <img src="files/1920x1200_494270_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
  
  
   <img src="files/dsc09678.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
  
  
   <img src="files/1920x1200_494270_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
  
  
   <img src="files/dsc09678.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
  
  
   <img src="files/1920x1200_494270_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg" class="img-thumbnail" onclick="openImageWindow(this.src);" style="cursor:pointer;" width="300" height="300" alt="" title="">
  
      </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Well you will need to create the appropriate HTML structure that whatever slider script/library you are using, expects to be able to work correctly.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. What exactly is the difference between your PHP output and the working HTML? edit: scratch that, your code is producing a table while the working example is just a bunch of <img>s in a <div>. You might want to fix this glaring difference.

Comment: _"And here is how the code looks when this script is in the slider"_ - are you saying that all those table, tr, td elements you created in your first script, have suddenly disappeared? Then that probably indicates that this is not the kind of structure the slider script was expecting in the first place.

Comment: I am new to php. How can I then specify the photo from the database in the slider, despite the fact that the photo will change for each user in different ways

Comment: @Chris G  Corrected. Indicated in code

Comment: If each photo belongs to a user, you need to add a `user_id` column to your photos table and add `WHERE user = ?` to your query. This is called a one-to-many relationship (*one* user has *many* photos) and is best solved that way. The next task is to change your `$output` to the expected format. This is not really a PHP issue, you just need to remove the html parts that you don't need from the string, like <tr> and <td> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JS to change the item.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 200px;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" onclick="currentSlide(1)" checked=""/>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" onclick="currentSlide(2)" />
  <input type="radio" name="switch" onclick="currentSlide(3)" />
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/moc7wzX.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1GR4azu.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObWbI.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: Image are taken randomly on imgur.

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Comment: If it fix your issue, you can click on the check mark at top left of my post !